# VirtualBox host-only network, cannot ping host from guest

Tags: virtualbox, ping, hosts, host-only, guest

I have the following setup:
Host machine Windows:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.103
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Guest machine Ubuntu  in VirtualBox:

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:01:85:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.33.3/24 brd 192.168.33.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 359sec preferred_lft 359sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe01:85e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft foreve
```

VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1454:89c9:eb7c:9d6d%37
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.33.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

VirtualBox DHCP:

```
Server 192.168.33.2
Mask 255.255.255.0
Lower addr 192.168.33.3
Upper addr 192.168.33.254
```

I can easily `ping` from the Host machine Windows to the guest:

```
ping 192.168.33.3

Pinging 192.168.33.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.33.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.33.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.33.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

It does not work for me otherwise. Namely, I cannot ping from the Guest Ubuntu to the Host Windows:

```
ping 192.168.0.103
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

P.S. I even tried to modify the guest's address to 192.168.0.3 to match the host's network and the actual result was the same:
I could not ping from the Guest Ubuntu to the Host Windows machine `192.168.0.103`.

However, the guest (Ubuntu) can ping VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter:

```
ping 192.168.33.1
PING 192.168.33.1 (192.168.33.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.33.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.378 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.430 ms
```

VirtualBox has this table:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

```
Host-only:
VM→Host +
VM←Host +
VM1↔VM2 +
VM→Net/LAN -
VM←Net/LAN -
```

Is it normal VirtualBox behavior? (I saw threads that people can ping from guest to host in this mode).
What am I missing?

Comment: Also notice that Windows firewall blocks icmp echo request by default, so you might need to have a look at that and enable these rules if they're not enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same setup - a Windows host with an Ubuntu VM on it.  And the same problem.
I could ping the guest from the host, but not the other way around.  I was using a bridged adapter in the VM settings, and I entirely removed the Host Only adapter VirtualBox created...

The problem turned out to be the Windows Defender Firewall!  As a shotgun approach, I just disabled it entirely, and tested... presto!

Ideally, one would want to add a firewall rule to open a pinhole for a specific ip range, port, protocol...  Try the shotgun first to see if you have the same essential issue.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the Ubuntu VM couldn't communicate with the MySQL of the host.  Added mysqld.exe to the allowed apps in Windows Defender and the connection worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Your host PC has multiple networking interfaces and multiple IP addresses.  Its difficult to say for sure, but based on the information you've provided it looks like the IP `192.168.0.103` is likely your standard network interface.  VirtualBox has created a second network interface called the "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" and given that adapter the IP of `192.168.33.1`.

Since you can ping `192.168.33.1` from your guest VM you CAN ping the host computer from the guest, but you can only ping the interface/IP that is shared with the VM.  Your PC will not route the network traffic from the host-only interface to your real network interface.

As for capturing traffic using Wireshark, it appears the Wireshark [can only use physical interfaces](https://superuser.com/a/1306308/820) and the host-only interface is a [software interface created by VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) so you likely won't be able to capture from it.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal for Host Only mode in Virtual Box.

[https://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/443class/docs/vbox_host-only_setup.html#:~:text=With%20host%2Donly%20networking%2C%20virtual,in%20VirtualBox%20on%20the%20host](https://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/443class/docs/vbox_host-only_setup.html#:%7E:text=With%20host%2Donly%20networking%2C%20virtual,in%20VirtualBox%20on%20the%20host).

> A VirtualBox host-only adapter can also function as a DHCP server to
> assign ip addresses to VirtualBox virtual machines. The host machine
> (and other virtual machines if any) can then connect to the virtual
> machines using these ip addresses using ssh or sftp (provided an ssh
> server is running on the virtual machine).
>
> This does mean virtual machines using host-only can't access the
> outside world, but in particular, the host should be able to use ssh
> to login to a virtual machine (with an ssh server running) and sftp to
> transfer files between the host and the virtual machine.

Consider using Bridged or NAT mode if you wish to interconnect. That will work.

Comment: VirtualBox states that it is possible to ping the host from guest in the host-only network mode:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: Host Mode is for isolating the guest, so I think the information in the article I posted applies.  From your link  "Instead, a virtual network interface, similar to a loopback interface, is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host."  . So you need the ideas supplied in my answer.  I do not think Ping will work.

Comment: I need this congif for Wireshark.

Comment: Try another networking mode to accommodate Wire Shark.

Comment: Nothing else is working to catch the traffic from VM to host. 
It only works backward when I send packets from host to guest. 
Host-only is the mode everyone suggests for Wireshark to catch traffic from VMs.

Comment: Host only isolates a guest machine and so hampers traffic flow by design. Why not use an unfettered networking mode for this.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem, and found this

[https://bitlaunch.io/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-pingable/#:~:text=You'll%20be%20taken%20to,allow%20ping%20in%20Windows%2010](https://bitlaunch.io/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-pingable/#:%7E:text=You%27ll%20be%20taken%20to,allow%20ping%20in%20Windows%2010).

In windows, all you have to do is configure firewal and enable this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TDHF.png)

Hope I've helped

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.